# UWP how to export RadGridView`s content

Tags: telerik, uwp, telerik-grid

I've been working recently with Telerik UI for UWP on a personal app with a RadDataGrid component, but I can not find a method of exporting data to Excel format. Is this implemented the extension methods or the fuctionality was dropped? Could you please guide me about it? Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems like Telerik is paid third party package, why not ask support from Telerik team?

Comment: why not convert the source of the data in the grid into csv format (comma separated values). the file can then be opened in excel.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT, what's the point? Product tag are legion on SO. For "relatively inactive" Product tag is ok to use company tag. Bonus: Telerik UI for UWP is free. If you are asking if those product tag can be useful anyhow on SO just check [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254251/6560478) it's about an other tag bug same ish

Comment: I didn't use any UWP. But i have been spam by this "new" "awsome" "free produc"t, "try it now!". So I assume it was all free awsome.. and only the support and the dev pack was a paid one. So my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the UWP DataGrid doesn't have built-in exporting. [We do have it logged in the Feedback Portal](https://feedback.telerik.com/Project/167/Feedback/Details/185173-grid-ability-to-export-data-to-excel), you can add your "upvote" by clicking the Like button.

**Side-note:**

If you are using [the open source version](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP) of UI for UWP (i.e. the nuget packages vs the Extensions SDK), StackOverflow is the correct place to ask questions.

If you have a licensed version (trial or paid), then you can [submit a support ticket here](https://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets/contact-support-team) (directly from the engineering team).

[See here for the official support options](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP#getting-help).